# Bow/BowBack threads lock explanation

Tags: java, multithreading

Regarding this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html

We have Bow/BowBack example that i can't understand, i would like a detailed explanation of what's realy happening

Indeed i remove some lines that i dont understand their purpose :

```
    if (! (myLock && yourLock)) {
        if (myLock) {
             lock.unlock();
        }
        if (yourLock) {
             bower.lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

and it still working !

What is the purpose to get the lock then release it just after,

before doing the job ? then release it again after finishing the job !!

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.Random;    
public class Safelock {
    static class Friend {
        private final String name;
        private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();    
        public Friend(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }    
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }    
        public boolean impendingBow(Friend bower) {
            Boolean myLock = false;
            Boolean yourLock = false;
            try {
                myLock = lock.tryLock();
                yourLock = bower.lock.tryLock();
            } finally {
                if (! (myLock && yourLock)) {
                    if (myLock) {
                        lock.unlock();
                    }
                    if (yourLock) {
                        bower.lock.unlock();
                    }
                }
            }
            return myLock && yourLock;
        }                
        public void bow(Friend bower) {
            if (impendingBow(bower)) {
                try {
                    System.out.format("%s: %s has"
                        + " bowed to me!%n", 
                        this.name, bower.getName());
                    bower.bowBack(this);
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                    bower.lock.unlock();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.format("%s: %s started"
                    + " to bow to me, but saw that"
                    + " I was already bowing to"
                    + " him.%n",
                    this.name, bower.getName());
            }
        }    
        public void bowBack(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s has" +
                " bowed back to me!%n",
                this.name, bower.getName());
        }
    }    
    static class BowLoop implements Runnable {
        private Friend bower;
        private Friend bowee;    
        public BowLoop(Friend bower, Friend bowee) {
            this.bower = bower;
            this.bowee = bowee;
        }        
        public void run() {
            Random random = new Random();
            for (;;) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(10));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                bowee.bow(bower);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Friend alphonse =
            new Friend("Alphonse");
        final Friend gaston =
            new Friend("Gaston");
        new Thread(new BowLoop(alphonse, gaston)).start();
        new Thread(new BowLoop(gaston, alphonse)).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tryLock()` returns true if the thread succeeded in obtaining the lock (or already had it). The code you don't understand tries to obtain both friends locks. If at least one of them couldn't be obtained:

```
if (! (myLock && yourLock)) {
```

then it releases the one that was obtained (if any):

```
    if (myLock) {
         lock.unlock();
    }
    if (yourLock) {
         bower.lock.unlock();
    }
```

because the whole point of the method is to return true if both locks were successfully obtained, and to return false, and not hold any of the locks, if both locks were not successfully obtained.

Comment: thank you very mutch, i thought it try to get the lock

Comment: To realease the locks that were obtained before, in `impendingBow(bower)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `finally` block is always executed, also when some runtime exception occurs while in the `try` block. It is used make sure the java program (in this case specifically the locks, but it's also often used to close streams) is in a 'valid' state exiting the `try` - `catch` - `finally` block.

In this case, as @JB Nizet posted, the goal is to return `true` when both locks are obtained, and `false` when no lock is obtained. When - due to some interruption, only one lock is obtained, the program is not in a desirable state. This is prevented by the code in the `finally` block: when only one lock is obtained, that lock is then released.